# Amusing 404 "Page Not Found" Images for Trilogy sites?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-exchange, 404-not-found

I'd like to have **amusing but on-topic images** for our 404 Page Not Found page on:

- Stack Overflow
- Server Fault
- Super User
- Meta

By on topic, I mean the **404 image** on Stack Overflow should be a programmery "not found" of some kind, and the Super User one should be a power user's "not found", and so forth.

These images would be shown in addition to the existing 404 page text, so nothing is getting lost, we're just trying to inject a little fun into the process.

I'm having trouble coming up with anything. Any good suggestions? Post them as answers!

If your submission or suggestion is highly voted and meets the criteria outlined, it's likely to be deployed as the "official" 404 image for one of the trilogy sites …

EDIT: 404 page winners!

- Mark Rushakoff : Stack Overflow
- squillman : Server Fault

The other two I selected myself.

Comment: Are you saying the power user sysadmin kitty cat of programming doesn't cover for all?

Comment: we already have per-site images for error pages. 404 is 100% text at the moment.

Comment: If someone wants to add images to my text, you're welcome to, since I didn't find any good ones.

Comment: Are the images themselves required, or is a concrete description of an image enough?

Comment: You could put in some ideas for images using keywords for google search.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to have a bounty here, when I assume there will be 4 "chosen" 404 pages (one for each site), but only one will get a bounty.

Comment: When I saw that headline, I misread it as "For the http://triolets.org site"

Comment: area51 needs one, too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53030/404-site-for-area51

Comment: why the bounty @PopularDemand?

Comment: @studiohack just because I like Mark's code. I didn't know it was created specifically for SO's 404 page until recently. I know it's only MSO rep, but I felt like doing _something_.

Comment: [Status-no-longer-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367993/custom-404-pages-are-gone) :(

Answer (score 139, accepted):

I'd like to see some kind of [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)) for Stack Overflow's 404 page.  Here's a little polyglot for Befunge-93, Brainf*ck, Python, Ruby, Perl, and C that simply prints 404 to stdout. It probably works in whatever other scripting languages that use `#` as a line comment and accept the keyword `print`. Could possibly add Whitespace as well, but that doesn't show up very well in images.

```
# define v putchar
#   define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

There were a couple things I didn't care for in the version that's up on the 404 page now, so I propose this modified version.  It still works in Perl/Python/Ruby/C/Befunge/BF (at 143 chars), but I got rid of the `exit` stuff since it didn't really add anything, and technically the BF output a `\0` that I didn't originally mean to have in there.

```
# define v putchar
#  define print(x) main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#++++++++4[>++++++<-]>++++.----.++++<*/
print(202*2)
#undef /*>.@*/v
```

I'm actually not sure if Perl needs a semicolon after `print(202*2)` — I can recall Perl requiring a semicolon after each statement, but Perl 5.10.0 on my machine doesn't complain, even with the `-W` flag.

Comment: good stuff, will use this for the SO 404 page

Comment: Just saw the 404 page when I logged out at work today -- that made my week!  Thanks for picking it!

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but in BF93 specification, it's up to interpreter how to handle undefined characters such as 'e'. So it's possible (and probable) that a befunge interpreter only print a single 0 and exits.

Comment: Perl requires a semicolon *between* statements, not *after* them, so if you've got only one statement you can do perfectly well without.

Comment: This doesn't work in Befunge at all, given there's only a single `.` on the path to the `@`

Comment: What Befunge interpreter does this work in?

Comment: @MDXF, Found it. The author says they used the [Visual Befunge Applet](http://www.ashleymills.com/?q=befunge_applet_lite). Unfortunately, it seems to be unavailable now. That implementation uses `e` to push the ASCII of 101 and multiplies it by 4 (note that this behaviour does not appear in any Befunge spec)

Answer (score 107):

Here's another for SF.  Found it [**here**](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/01/09/the-worst-cable-mess-ever/), not sure about permissions.

## 404: Server not found

[image]

Comment: holy crap that's a lot of ethernet cabling!

Comment: Someone should be shot.  Not fired.  Shot.

Comment: But once they are shot, no-one will ever be able to untangle it.

Comment: As one comment on the original blog post noted, it almost looks like straw balls...

Comment: http://englishrussia.com/?p=1836

Comment: His noodly appendage hath blessed the machinery: http://www.venganza.org/

Comment: Permissions would be the kicker on something like this.  Sure, we have all seen it a few times, but that doesn't make it public domain.  For a "professional" site like SO, using unlicensed images can get them in trouble.

Comment: this will be used on SF. I awarded to Mark because he wrote actual code!

Comment: Yeah, best I had was a pic.  If I created that I would have had to shoot myself :)

Answer (score 57):

For Stack Overflow (or any of the sites; it's a Star Wars reference).

[image: 404]

> 404: These are not the Droids you're looking for.

Or:

> 404: We couldn't find the Droids you were looking for. Try Google?

Comment: might be ok for Super User, but not programmery or sysadminy enough for SO/SF

Comment: @Jeff - but geeky enough...

Comment: Perhaps I don't have enough sense of humour, but I don't understand why this would come up with a 404 error.

Comment: @Kinopiko .. "These are not the droids you're looking for" .. sounds like "droids not found" to me :)

Comment: Cool but too much free advertisement.

Comment: Advertising for Google/ I'd be surprised if Google needed advertisement at this point.

Comment: Hey - who's this Google company? Never heard of them, look interesting.

Comment: This one needs to go on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's actually an advertisement for Linux, note the bar at the bottom.

Answer (score 40):

As usual I'm late to the party... :-)  The inline image sucks (auto sizing and all that)...

[image: Error 404]

**EDIT**:
Actually given some more thought to this (even though the bounty is over, I would do the 404 page as an actual question.  Asked by "Community" or "StackOverflow.com".  The text of the question would be the text/links on the current 404 page (and maybe the winning image from this question).  And for fun I would allow users to actually answer the question.  Imagine the chaos that could ensue... :-)

Comment: WTF? Are you logged in as community?

Comment: No just some creative cut & paste suing Firebug... :-)

Answer (score 25):

For Meta.

> Unfortunately, there are no waffles here.

*[Ed- Image no longer exists.]*

Comment: I think it needs more ponies.

Comment: Someone PS a pony somewhere in there.

Comment: add freehand circles with dropshadows!!

Comment: -1 Eyes are bleeding from the compression and for piggy-backing on the votes for the first edited version.

Comment: would it be better as a separate answer? i thought it would be douchy if i "stole" the image as a separate answer, so i presented it as an alternative form of this answer

Comment: After the amount of votes already on it, the change is way drastic and personally would rather see it as a new answer since it for all intents and context is a new candidate. You can have the au naturel or the so-lossy-you're-making-a-brown-sound versions to choose between.

Comment: okay I made it a separate answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/28031#28031

Comment: see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/free-waffles

Comment: woo do I get waffles as a prize?

Answer (score 25):

For any of the sites:

## "Despite his best efforts, Joel Spolsky was unable to locate the item in question"

or, more neutrally,

## "Despite our best efforts, we were unable to locate the item in question"

[Vintage image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m29M5.jpg)

([Original source](http://www-03.ibm.com/ibm/history/exhibits/vintage/images/4506VV4002.jpg) from Google Image search for "IBM punch cards")

Comment: Which site is this better aimed for?

Comment: I think it would go well with any of the sites.

Comment: I once found a Burroughs adding machine in an abandoned warehouse. It was integrated into a stand that seemed a little bigger than this but it was also rusted in place.

Comment: This machine is an "IBM 29 card punch", according to the original website.

Comment: s/Joel Spolsky/Jon Skeet/

Answer (score 24):

For SO

> It seems you're trying to access a page that doesn't exist. You should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: This is kind of a memme that the people most likely to find a broken link on SO wouldn't understand, I'm afraid. Is more meta material.

Comment: @voyager: For Meta you need: "You should totally drop shadows..."

Answer (score 24):

Stack Overflow:

```
function lookForPage(url) {
  if (pageExists(url)) {
    return page(url);
  } else {
    return lookForPage(url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

For ServerFault:

## "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."

or

## "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't find that."

http://www.drucker.ca/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/hal9000.gif

(from google image search for "hal 9000")

Answer (score 20):

**This could work on Super User:**

[image: Burnt Server]

### Error 404

Just for kicks, we tried:

```bash
sudo "make me a sandwich";
```

It didn't work. We'll be back up in a minute.

Comment: This one made me laugh!

Comment: Probably best not to intimate a 404 is a temporary thing, but otherwise funny! :)

Comment: @Phoshi: Oh yeah... wow... good call. Epic fail on my part. Maybe good for a error 500 though!

Answer (score 18):

For SO.

> It seems you've followed a dangling pointer.

<s>[original image](http://www.cznp.com/images/dangling_pointer.png)</s> (dead)

[image: substitute image]

Comment: a screenshot of code would work, in this case, I think.

Comment: I found some example code for a dangling pointer. Can be replaced.

Comment: BSOD?  ... (obligatory spaces)

Answer (score 17):

For Super User:

## "Your input could not be processed"

[(This is from a Google Image search for "cat keyboard")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrOKg.jpg)

Original: http://dontclickthis.whatingods.name/cat-on-keyboard.jpg

Comment: why is that person holding a network cable (or straw?!?!) near the cat's buttockal region?

Comment: @warren: connecting some cat 5?

Comment: @warren: it's the handle of whatever dangly toy they used to entice the kitten onto the keyboard in the first place.

Comment: maybe i'm overly morbid, but it looked like the guy was about to do an autopsy on the cat... :)

Comment: @Kip: may be he was debugging the cat after its process died unexpectedly.

Answer (score 17):

In honor of Geocities, [called home by the Lord today](http://latimesblogs.latimes.com/technology/2009/10/geocities-closing.html) at much too young an age:

[image: "under construction"]

Comment: The very first website I contributed to was there. Ah, we are nothing.

Answer (score 17):

[image]

This is for Super User

Comment: +1, this is usually how I feel inside whenever I get ANY 404 for something I was really looking for. It's actually making me think about it now, and making me upset.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Oscar the grouch]

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn circles.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a couple for SF/SU:

As suggested in comments

For Linux users:
[Not Found - Windows http://www.sqeq.com/image/SF_404.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/SF_404.jpg)

For Windows users:
[Not Found - KDE http://www.sqeq.com/image/SF_404_KDE.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/SF_404_KDE.jpg)

Someone will have to pick me up on the Mac Finder shot, I don't have a Mac lying around here...

Comment: Now if that would only show for non-Windows users, and come up with something similar for Linux/BSD/OSX/something that only shows for Windows users, I could get behind it. ;)

Comment: What about finder for Apple users.

Comment: This would also work well on SU.

Comment: The OS reversal was on purpose?

Comment: Yes, based on retracile's comment.  But doesn't have to be.

Comment: **Port 22 ?!?!**

Comment: @George: it's SSH...

Comment: @squill: Oops... didn't see the *"Enter a name for this Secure Shell..."* part

Answer (score 13):

Here's a play on a qmail bounce, for SF:

[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard Aside from Internet Archive being slow, it's highly unlikely to completely go down any time soon, so I don't see much point in making more duplicates of it.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 they may change the image name format, breaking all links to it. It's not meant to be hot linked, I'm 1000% sure of that. Please always copy all images to the dedicated image hosting of SE in imgur, that's exactly what it's meant for. And yes, there is much point in making as much duplicates of images, so they won't be lost. This is the policy in Stack Exchange, if you disagree feel free to start a discussion or feature request asking to change this policy.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sure, in most cases the dedicated hosting is handy and more robust, but in general image hostings are being created and shut down every 1-2 years. They also change link formats and what not even though they're _meant_ to be hot-linked. So we can't really be sure that the Imgur is more fire-proof than others; the Internet Archive is 1.5-2 times older. As for the duplicates, unless they're linked to the post somehow they won't be useful 'cause it won't be possible to find them. ;-) Haven't heard of this being a policy, though.

Comment: @EvgenKo423 not talking about imgur.com itself, i.e. uploading directly on imgur. I mean uploading here inside the editor of SE. They did not change format even one time, in all the years it exists, and even if they will, they will also automatically change all the links as it's their responsibility, unlike external image hosts.

Answer (score 11):

## Sorry, we can't find your page. You may have mistyped something.

[image: A monkey typing]

(from google image search for "monkey keyboard")

Comment: That just looks like a chimp at a keyboard. Where's the magical monkey keyboard with a banana as the space bar?

Comment: This is a visual joke about "monkeys typing Shakespeare". There is a better image on Google image search, but this one had a hotlinking block on it: http://www.maxpower.ca/wp-content/uploads/2006/09/monkeytypes.jpg

Answer (score 9):

For Meta

I took [Ólafur Waage/random's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites/27114#27114) and added freehand circles with dropshadows and [unnecessarily high JPEG compression](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000464.html).  ([Properly compressed version here](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/235/404good.jpg).)

> http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/160/404comp.jpg

Comment: Beautiful.  I promised myself I wouldn't cry.

Answer (score 8):

For StackOverflow: punch cards scattered across the floor and the text: "Error: We didn't find that hole."

Comment: **Error:** unable to find correct <s>punchcard</s>data

Answer (score 7):

For SuperUser: A generic super-hero's costume (incorporating the logo colors?), on either hanger or a mannequin, with the text "404 Hero not found".

Comment: Really needs images in an images discussion.

Comment: Fair enough; I'll bow out.

Answer (score 4):

For Meta: a picture of that "Thinker" statue in a ditch of dirty water; "404: Amazingly, that's one thing we *didn't* find here."

Answer (score 3):

For StackOverflow: reams upon reams of green-bar paper with (presumably) code printouts, along with the text "What line did you say that was again?"

Comment: Too bad I threw out all that green-bar with the COBOL code from college... I could have totally used that for a visual.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a picture but it's still a funny 404 message. Unfortunately you will have to click the link: [Depressed Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20030204071645/http://www.tud.ttu.ee/error.html). If someone knows how to make it show up here without having to click the link please edit my post so it will.

Comment: Although it's funny, it wouldn't make a very good 404 page for real errors, since the already-frustrated user would not want to sit there watching someone's joke message scroll past.

Comment: But it is a real 404 page.  The Marvin-robot is one of my favorites.  But it's been done- need something new here.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Originally from http://my.yougov.com/App_Portals/yougov/templates/en/images/error_404.jpg]

This is for Server Fault.

Comment: From iStockPhoto?

Answer (score 2):

404, the waffles are outdoors today.:
[Waffles and Dinges http://www.wafelsanddinges.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/webassets/.pond/Newtruckpostcard5.jpg.w560h527.jpg](http://www.wafelsanddinges.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderpictures/webassets/.pond/Newtruckpostcard5.jpg.w560h527.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, again, I don't understand the joke.

Comment: The joke is that when Spider-Man tried to save Gwen Stacy from falling off the bridge, he ended up snapping her neck and killing her.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [nice collection](http://webdesignledger.com/inspiration/404-error-pages-for-your-viewing-pleasure) of images for inspiration.  An amusing image is a good idea, but I would take the "URL as part of the UI" metaphor one step further.  Turn the *juicy bits* of the miss-typed URL into a search.

If they type something starting with

- **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/** - Search for a question with the rest of the URL.  If it has a big number (like a question ID) that isn't found, then discard it.
- **https://stackoverflow.com/tags/** - Search for a tag, if there is nothing close, then search for a question.
- **https://stackoverflow.com/users** - Search for a user, if there are no results, search their profile.
- **https://stackoverflow.com/badges** - You get the idea . . .

You could put some other parsing in there to make a more educated guess for what they were going for.  Apply the same pattern to any site in the trilogy, or for that matter on Stack Exchange.

Comment: a serious answer to a not-serious request, though...

Comment: Well, I opened with the link to the collection of 404 pages so that I wouldn't end up too serious.

Answer (score -3):

We made you a question ... but we eated it.

Comment: The grammar is acceptable for a LOLCAT message, but the spelling is far too accurate.