# What is the code on Stack Overflow's 'Page Not Found' pages?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, source-code, 500-server-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the joke in the Stack Overflow 404 page code?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28625/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code)

For example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/does_not_exist

What is the code on the right pane, and if it is a real language, what does it do exactly?

Comment: I should point out, I can work out it is printing 404, but what's all the other code doing?

Comment: This. Is. C. Obfuscated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's [polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29) code - that is code that will compile unaltered in more than one language, all of which write 404 to `stdout`.

I can spot at least

- C
- [Brainfuck](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/)
- Multitude of scripting languages (Python, Perl, ...)

See [Amusing 404 "Page Not Found" Images for Trilogy sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites)

Answer (score 6):

I think it was created on Meta : [Amusing 404 "Page Not Found" Images for Trilogy sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites) and is not a specific language, but multiple.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a mixture of obsfucated C and [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

Answer (score 2):

Fancy and esoteric ways of printing '404'

Answer (score 2):

I know line three is [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Go figure out what it does :-)