# 404 page for Area 51

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, area-51, 404-not-found

In accordance with [Jeff's discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites). Currently [Area 51 shows the SO-404](http://area51.stackexchange.com/404).

**Edit** I put a bounty on this to motivate suggestions. Please note however that the accepted answer will not necessarily be implemented since I have no saying on that. But still, you get 100 rep.

**Edit2.5** The decision was for David's
[image: no trespassing]

I thank you all for your great ideas!

Comment: The links on PageNotFound have been cleaned up so they're not broken any more. We'll monitor this question and be on the general lookout for a new hilarious picture for our 404 :)

Comment: Crap. Can't find a high res Lazlo Hollyfeld picture. Isn't he the one who came up with the site?

Comment: At least they are constant with Area 51 in doing their own thing without caring about community suggestions :-]

Comment: How about using the 'case of the mondays' image. That'll scare any would-be trespassers away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found this one

[image]

Comment: Yes, because with a photo of the actual "Area 51", you won't have any problem with the authorities :-]

Answer (score 24):

**"When you searched for this site, there was no 404, but you spent a nice time in Roswell, New Mexico"**

[image]

*edit*
or (thanks to Gnoupi for reminding me)

[image]

**edit** maybe a better line would be

**"The page you were looking for is not here. You haven't seen a 404. In fact, there is no area51. You have spent all day at stackoverflow"**

Comment: Possible other picture for the same idea (a bit smaller): http://gadgetophilia.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/t10neuralizer.jpg

Comment: @gnoupi funny you mention that one, I first considered it, too :) I'll edit it as another option

Comment: Note sure how we are doing with rights, though, for such kind of image.

Comment: @gnoupi good question, maybe we could find a similar one that is freely available as promotional material

Comment: A way to solve the "rights" issue would be to have Jeff and Joel (or Robert) act the first photo in person :-] With the suits, glasses and all that.

Comment: I only see one picture (the second one) is there a first one?

Comment: @C. Ross: The tingling means it's working.

Comment: We liked this, but were worried about getting sued :\

Comment: @David - get Jeff and Joel together (or another couple of developers, for example), and act it? :)

Answer (score 12):

[image: Not the page you're looking for]

**"This is not the page you're looking for..."**

Comment: https://github.com/404 hm...

Answer (score 6):

[image]

See, it's only a weather balloon.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Cartman Anal Probe]

**Run!!! They're coming!!!**