# Why is the logo used on the Stack Exchange data explorer different from the standard Stack Exchange logo?

Tags: support, bug, data-explorer, logo

Here is the standard Stack Exchange logo:

[image: Stack Exchange logo]

Now here is the one used on the Data Explorer:

[image: Stack Exchange logo from Data Explorer]

As you can see, the text is a different font and the 3D styles on the speech bubble are different in each logo. Is this discrepancy intended, or is it a bug?

Comment: font style of g is different......

Comment: I don't know why, but it is likely because it is the [adopted child of Stack Exchange](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/06/14/leaving-stack-exchange) and not an in-house developed site.

Comment: character "K" also different, look closely

Comment: Following @psubsee2003 correct observation, it's probably different on purpose as the original logo is copyrighted by Stack Exchange so whoever created Data Explorer in the first place (Sam, I think) did not want any trouble so he just went and created his own version. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it's ancient.  Jin actually mentioned this to me after a call the other day.

We'll be fixing this as well as several other style fix ups in the next few weeks.  We're just waiting on some server hardware to arrive in Oregon so we can move SEDE back out there and get it back on speedy hardware.  Possibly before that, we'll have the homepage and other tweaks in; Oded will be working a bit on it soon as time allows.

Comment: Yes. Finally, an official answer!

Comment: Can you mark this [meta-tag:status-planned] or [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Oh, someone else is already working on that? :P

Answer (score 11):

I definitely agree that this is a huge issue. I propose standardizing the font used in the logo for Maximum Professionalism™:

[image: Comic Sans SE]

This will fix all logo-related problems.

As suggested by [Gabriele Petronella](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204769/why-is-the-logo-used-on-the-stack-exchange-data-explorer-different-from-the-stan/207053#comment658380_207053) I failed to live up to the standards of professionalism in logo design that all designers must strive for. I present you Maximum Professionalism²™:

[image: Word Art Logo Comic Sans SE]

Yes folks, you may [tattoo this on to your body with proper attribution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194734/can-i-tattoo-the-stack-overflow-404-polyglot/194740#194740)*

<sup>* Barring the actual logo portion in the top right corner, you have to leave that out</sup>

Comment: Are you referring to FIRST LEGO League's Gracious Professionalism?

Comment: @gparyani how could a million PowerPoint presentations and flyers distributed by the PTAs of the world be wrong? Comic Sans is the font of the future for all needs big and small. It is inviting, friendly, and it just screams **professional**

Comment: Then why didn't Microsoft Bob use it? After all, Comic Sans was invented *specifically* for use with Microsoft Bob.

Comment: I would prefer Segoe UI. The Windows 8 version.

Comment: WordArt anyone?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, I fixed it for you.

Comment: I upvoted before the WordArt. I wish I could upvote again.

Comment: I think you forgot something. The `kerning` in the original logo is not the same as the `kerning` here.

Comment: Don't you mean `keming`, @gparyani? ;)

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen That's why I formatted it as code...

Comment: We are going for professional. Why would we ever muck with the defaults? Fiddling with keming is for amateurs!

Comment: @Gabriele, sorry about the misspelling of your name!