# Meta.SE 404 page is boring

Tags: discussion, design, meta, images, 404-not-found

The [Trilogy sites have fun 404 pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites):

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/404):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[Super User](https://superuser.com/404):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/404#):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

And, my favorite, [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/404):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But [Meta.SE's 404 page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/404) is very boring:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Yawn.

[image]

And it isn't like I'm seeing this infrequently - we get spam, it is deleted and then I click the X new questions button, open them all in new tabs and half of them are deleted and end up with a 404.

Please could we have a fun, inventive image, maybe that links into one of [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/). Feel free to answer with your suggested images (ensure it would be legal for it to be used).

Please note however that SE have not said that the 404 page will necessarily be implemented since I have no saying on that.

Comment: I have asked this question myself but can't find it :D

Comment: @rene Oh, this was the question old mine was dupe of... So mine was deleted apparently...

Comment: Lol, i closed it twice :p