# Can we have a more amusing error page for Meta?

Tags: feature-request, meta, 404-not-found

Once upon a very long time ago, Jeff Atwood posted [Amusing 404 [images] for Trilogy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27112/amusing-404-page-not-found-images-for-trilogy-sites).  The list included Meta, but it looks like it got left out, according to the [bland oops](https://meta.stackexchange.com/error) and [404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/erro) pages.  I rather like the waffle keyboard for [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/d), and the frustrated guy on [Super User](https://superuser.com/guy).  Perhaps something including "Try again in 6-8 minutes"?

Comment: Given that we officially discontinued doing custom error pages/images for site designs, highly unlikely. If anything, we'd be more likely to remove all the existing custom 404 images network-wide at some point than add more.

Comment: @animuson That's... a shame.  I really liked the waffles.  Is there an official post declaring that, or a blog post?

Comment: I don't believe that policy was ever "officially" announced, but there is a question asking for an official response that never got one: [Why don't newly-designed sites get custom 404, 500, or captcha images anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333586/why-dont-newly-designed-sites-get-custom-404-500-or-captcha-images-anymore) Do note: I'm not saying we have plans to ever remove those images, just trying to emphasize how unlikely it is we'd reverse course there.

Comment: At the very least we have a better 404 image than Meta Super User: https://meta.superuser.com/guy

Comment: @Glorfindel At least it's unique.

Comment: @animuson Is there a plan for the team to leave an official response on that question?

Comment: At the least we would expect MSE to share the fine image of it's main site: 404 image https://meta.stackexchange.com/guy vs. Panda Sign: https://stackexchange.com/guy

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95Bvw.png

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252742/meta-se-404-page-is-boring