# Is changing the "Page Not Found" title to something dedicates to its site a good idea?

Tags: discussion, title, 404-not-found

To start of, I'd like to begin with my question on Meta Academia SE: [What does the image in the “404 error” page mean?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1872/14341)

The metaphor of broken link image in Academia is a broken bike:

[image]

Palu Macil in his answer has made a very interesting idea. It plays on **Route not found**. So why don't we customize that title too?

Some ideas that I come up:

- Math: No solution
- Stack Overflow: Missing library
- English: Cat got my tongue

If you afraid that the users will be confused, I think we just need to add *404* at the beginning of the title. I think *404* is popular enough to be recognized.

Found this after posting this question: [Amusing 404 “Page Not Found” Images for Trilogy sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27112/260800)

Comment: When you move cheese someone will complain: I rely on Page not found in the title of the tab when flagging spam reports from the Tavern chatroom. With this change I have to remember each and every 404 catch phrase...

Comment: Did you mean(in the 2nd last para) adding 404 to the current "Page Not Found" text displayed above the error message on the left? So it would look like "404 Page Not Found"

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting question. Here is what I found upon doing some investigation on the current "404 page not found" across the popular Stack Exchange Network sites.

There seems to be a some kind of tradition or an established standard that SE's team has been following. The current 404 error page of Meta.Academia seems to be ***inline*** with the other popular SE Network sites.

The pattern I noticed here is the *error message* along with "**Page Not Found**" is displayed on the *left* and the corresponding *image* is on the *right* side of the message. This could possibly be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). It would be great if someone from the SE team can share some info about this. Here are a few screenshots for comparison:

**Stack Overflow:**

> [image]

**Server Fault:**

> [image]

**Super User:**

> [image]

**Ask Ubuntu:**

> [image]

**Stack Apps:**

> [image]

**Stack Exchange:**

> [image]

**Area 51:**

> [image]

**Meta SE:** (Please note *404* is an image)

> [image]

**Meta Academia:** (OP's website in the question)

> [image]